# How to get access to $route in meanjs controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, meanjs, ngroute

I am trying to get access to the current route since I added a title on it.

So the route looks something like

```
state('reports', {
    title: 'Reports',
    url: '/reports',
    templateUrl: 'modules/feeditems/views/reports.client.view.html'
}).
```

I want to get access to the title. so I can put it on my page Header. So in the Header controller I thought I could just get it off my

```
angular.module('core').controller('HeaderController', ['$rootScope', '$route', '$scope', 'Authentication', 'Menus',     
function($rootScope, $route, $scope, Authentication, Menus) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;         
        $scope.isCollapsed = false;
        $scope.menu = Menus.getMenu('topbar');
        $scope.$route = $route;
        console.log ('typeof($route) = ' + typeof($route));
        console.log ('typeof($route.current) = ' + typeof($route.current));
```

and I get the following error

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider <- $route

so I add ngRoute

```
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('core', ['ngRoute']);
```

then I get the following error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module r2h
>   due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module core
>   due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   ngRoute due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument.

How am I supposed to include this properly? the meanjs way?

Comment: Are you using `ui-router` or `ngRoute`?  Your route definition shows that you're using `state`, which would be `ui-router`, but everything else looks like you're asking for help with `ngRoute`

Comment: @Tom ui-router. That is my first problem. I thought I was using ngRoute but it is actually ui-router. But I still can't seem to get title out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused, MeanJS standard configuration uses Angular UI Router

### For Angular UI Router

You need to `angular-ui-router.js` then include `ui.router` inside your app dependency

After that in configuration do register your `state` using `$stateProvider`

**Syntax**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider){

    $stateProvider.state('reports', {
        url: '/reports',
        templateUrl: 'modules/feeditems/views/reports.client.view.html'
    })

})
```

For adding title dynamically you could refer [**this SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23814161/2435473)

Comment: so it looks like I am using Angular UI Router. How do I then get the title out?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28252931/4380266
. This has the solution to your problem.

Check the sequence you loaded your angular files.
The sequence must be :

```
angular.js 
angular-route.js 
finally your angular scripts
```